# Simulating CoordinatesToolOptions (for CDF) & the Inflexibility of MousePosition

Tags: plotting, cdf-format, tooltip

I got two lists of equal lengths, which I show in two `ListPlot`s, arranged in a `Column` or `GraphicsColumn` (whatever works). When I mouse over any of the two `ListPlot`s, I want to show the y-values of both `ListPlot`s tooltip style right where the mouse is.

I know how to do this using `CoordinatesToolOptions`; however, that's not an option, because it has to work in CDF, and it appears that the coordinate tool (pressing "." after having selected a graphic) does not work in CDF.

So I'm trying to simulate this behavior with `Epilog`, `Text`, `MousePosition`, `Mouseover`; in what I tried, I find that the behavior of MousePosition is weird, which might be due to my lack of understanding.

So first of all, here is the functionality I'd like to simulate.

```
With[{
    top = 0.5 RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100] + Table[Sin[0.0628 i], {i, 100}],
    bot = 0.5 RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100] + Table[Cos[0.0628 i], {i, 100}]
},
With[{ttDisplayFun = Function[pt, 
    Column[{
        Row[{"top ", top[[Min[100, Max[1, Round[pt[[1]]]]]]]}],
        Row[{"bot ", bot[[Min[100, Max[1, Round[pt[[1]]]]]]]}]
    }]
]},
With[{opts = {Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 400, 
    CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> ttDisplayFun}}},
        Dynamic@Column[{ListPlot[top, opts], ListPlot[bot, opts]}]
]]]
```

[image: want]

Now, trying it without `CoordinatesToolOptions`, I got no problem displaying the desired tooltip underneath the two plots.

```
With[{
    top = 0.5 RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100] + Table[Sin[0.0628 i], {i, 100}],
    bot = 0.5 RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100] + Table[Cos[0.0628 i], {i, 100}]
},
Dynamic@Column[{
    ListPlot[top, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 400],
    ListPlot[bot, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 400],
    With[{mouse = MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, {0, 0}]},
        With[{mouseX = mouse[[1]], mouseY = mouse[[2]]}, Column[{
            "good: mouse coords are in units used in the plot",
            "y values of top and bot easy to retrieve",
            "bad: I want this displayed tooltip style wherever the mouse is",
            Row[{"mouseX: ", mouseX}],
            Row[{"mouseY: ", mouseY}],
            Row[{"top: ", top[[Min[100, Max[1, Round[mouseX]]]]]}],
            Row[{"bot: ", bot[[Min[100, Max[1, Round[mouseX]]]]]}]
        }]]
    ]
}]]
```

[image: underneath]

First thing I tried was to move the code into Epilog.

```
With[{
    top = 0.5 RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100] + Table[Sin[0.0628 i], {i, 100}],
    bot = 0.5 RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100] + Table[Cos[0.0628 i], {i, 100}]
},
Dynamic@Column[{
    ListPlot[top, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 400, Epilog -> With[
        {mouse = MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, {99999, 99999}]},
            Text[Style[Framed[Column[{
                "I am Lazarus", "+++++++++",
                Row[{"top: ", top[[Min[100, Max[1, Round[mouse[[1]]]]]]]}],
                Row[{"bot: ", bot[[Min[100, Max[1, Round[mouse[[1]]]]]]]}]
            }]]
            , Background -> LightYellow, FontSize -> 16]
            , mouse, {-0.5, 1.4}]
        ]],
    ListPlot[bot, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 400, Epilog -> With[
        {mouse = MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, {99999, 99999}]},
            Text[Style[Framed[Column[{
                "I am Lazarus", "---------",
                Row[{"top: ", top[[Min[100, Max[1, Round[mouse[[1]]]]]]]}],
                Row[{"bot: ", bot[[Min[100, Max[1, Round[mouse[[1]]]]]]]}]
            }]]
            , Background -> LightYellow, FontSize -> 16]
            , mouse, {-0.5, 1.4}]
        ]]
    }]
]
```

[image: lazarus]

`MousePosition` will always return coordinates, when the mouse is over *one* of the two `ListPlot`s; I'd rather have `MousePosition` only return something (other than the default), if the mouse is over that `ListPlot` in the `Epilog` of which I'm calling `MousePosition`. There obviously *should* be a way to tell `MousePosition`, that one is interested *only* in the coordinates, when the mouse is over *some specific* graphic. Is there a way to do that?

Anyway, my next attempt was to use `GraphicsColumn` instead of column, because that has an Epilog option, which `Column` doesn't. (I actually would prefer `Column`, since `GraphicsColumn` adds lightyears of superfluous white space.) But now it turns out that in the Epilog of `GraphicsColumn`, we're dealing with a whole new coordinate system. I'd like to refer to *any* of the two coordinate systems of the two plots (don't matter which, since I need only the horizontal component, and that's the same for both.) So it's kind of the same problem as above; `MousePosition` appears to be inflexible. Am I missing something?

```
With[{
    top = 0.5 RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100] + Table[Sin[0.0628 i], {i, 100}],
    bot = 0.5 RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100] + Table[Cos[0.0628 i], {i, 100}]
},
Dynamic@Column[{
    GraphicsColumn[{
        ListPlot[top, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 400],
        ListPlot[bot, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 400]
    }
    , Epilog -> With[
        {mouse = MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, {99999, 99999}]},
            Text[Style[Framed[Column[{"wrong coordinate system", mouse}]]
            , Background -> LightYellow, FontSize -> 16], mouse, {-1, 2}]
        ]]
    }]
]
```

[image: wrong coordinate system]

This post is getting too long, what I tried with Mouseover didn't work either.

So ideally, what I'd want would be something like

```
MousePosition[<specific graphics object>,...]
```

or

```
If[CurrentGraphic[] == someGraphic, ...]
```

**update**

Well, I answered my own question below, but I still have no clue whether or not the above things that I would wish one could do with `MouseCoordinates` are possible. Are they?

Answer (score 4):

```
With[{
    top = 0.5 RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100] + Table[Sin[0.0628 i], {i, 100}],
    bot = 0.5 RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100] + Table[Cos[0.0628 i], {i, 100}],
    opts = {Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 400}
},
With[{epi = Function[{}, With[
        {mouse = MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}, {99999, 99999}]},
            Text[Style[Framed[Column[{
                Row[{"top: ", top[[Min[100, Max[1, Round[mouse[[1]]]]]]]}],
                Row[{"bot: ", bot[[Min[100, Max[1, Round[mouse[[1]]]]]]]}]
            }]]
        , Background -> LightYellow, FontSize -> 16], mouse, {-0.5, 2}]
    ]]
},
Column[{
    Mouseover[
        ListPlot[top, opts, Epilog -> {}],
        Dynamic@ListPlot[top, opts, Epilog -> epi[]]
    ],
    Mouseover[
        ListPlot[bot, opts, Epilog -> {}],
        Dynamic@ListPlot[bot, opts, Epilog -> epi[]]
    ]}]
]]
```